# Looping through object and printing child nodes

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I have the following object and if the user is on the French site (/fr), then show the French (fr) headers. To achieve this, I'm trying to loop through the object.

```js
var departments = {
  "Department-1": [{
    "fr": "Dept 1 - French",
    "en": "Dept 1"
  }],
  "Department-2": [{
    "fr": "Dept 2 - French",
    "en": "Dept 2"
  }],
  "Department-3": [{
    "fr": "Dept 3 - French",
    "en": "Dept 3"
  }]
}
if (true || window.location.href.indexOf("fr") > -1) { // true is for this snippet
  for (var key in departments) {
    if (departments.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key + " -> " + departments[key]);
      $(".department").append('<option value="' + key + '">' + key + '</option>');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="department"></select>
```

The above has the following console log:

```
Department-1 -> [object Object]
Department-2 -> [object Object]
Department-3 -> [object Object]
```

And my `select` markup looks like this:

```
<select class="department" name="department" id="department">
  <option>Department-1</option>
  <option>Department-2</option>
  <option>Department-3</option>
</select>
```

Whereas I'm after:

```
<select class="department" name="department" id="department">
  <option>Dept 1 - French</option>
  <option>Dept 2 - French</option>
  <option>Dept 3 - French</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You are getting `[object Object]`, because you are forcing the object into a string context in your console.log call. Don’t do that, don’t concatenate complex objects with other stuff using the `+` operator.

Comment: I made you the proper snippet you could have made from the start

Comment: You are only putting `key` into your options as their text content. What you actually want to put there, is `departments[key][0][LANG]`, with `LANG` being either `fr` or `en`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this map

If you use Object.entries, you need `entry[1][0][lang]`

```js
var departments = {
  "Department-1": [{
    "fr": "Dept 1 - French",
    "en": "Dept 1"
  }],
  "Department-2": [{
    "fr": "Dept 2 - French",
    "en": "Dept 2"
  }],
  "Department-3": [{
    "fr": "Dept 3 - French",
    "en": "Dept 3"
  }]
}
lang = "fr"; // from location
$(".department").append(
  Object.keys(departments)
    .map(key => { 
      const opt = departments[key][0][lang]; 
      return `<option value="${opt}">${opt}</option>` 
    })
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="department">
<option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```